# How to integrate `Watch Connectivity` safely only for iOS 9 users with the App which is still having iOS7 as minimum development target?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchconnectivity

I am currently working on an App which is **still supporting iOS 7 (minimum development target)**, but I got a requirement to integrate `Watch Connectivity` **only for the users who are using iOS 9.** Therefore I created a **singleton** named `WatchConnectivityManager` and it is having a private member like this.

```
private let session: WCSession? = WCSession.isSupported() ? WCSession.defaultSession() : nil
```

Everything works fine on iOS 9 but with iOS 8 and 7 I am getting crash exactly on the above line even though my `WatchConnectivityManager` singleton class definition starts as follows.

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
class WatchConnectivityManager: NSObject, WCSessionDelegate {
    ....
}
```

Any help to overcome this situation will be appreciated.

**NB:** I can easily perform version check allover the places where I am using `WCSession` related code. But is there any way to integrate that check **only inside** the `WatchConnectivityManager` singleton implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the answer which is simply adding

```
NSClassFromString("WCSession") != nil
```

check before any usage of `WCSession`class like this.

```
private let session: WCSession? = NSClassFromString("WCSession") != nil && WCSession.isSupported() ? WCSession.defaultSession() : nil
```

Any more better answers?